# Dark Souls 3 NPC'S summons

Tags: ps4, dark-souls-3

So, I heard/read about two summon signs in front of Vordt of the Boreal Valley. I already killed the boss, but, how do they appear? I´m very confused with how to summon or find Lion Knight Albert and Master Sword. I read all you need to do is kill the dude with the katana that is just left to Firelink Shrine – I did that – but neither of them were there. Am I missing something? I don't care to fight with the boss, I just want to know what I did wrong since I´m a completionist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sword Master's sign will be right outside of Vordt's boss room after he's been defeated at Firelink Shrine until Vordt is defeated.

Lion Knight Albert's sign will be further up, available until Vordt is defeated.

Neither will be available for summon after Vordt has been defeated (until the next NG+).

Keep in mind you must be in Enkindled mode (ember restored) in order summon help to your world.

Comment: That's the thing. I defeated Sword Master and he wasn't there. And, do I need to do something before to see the sign of Lion Knight? Cause he wasn't there neither. (I saw the locations of the sign, so yeah, I didn't miss them)

Comment: Oh, I need to have ember restored in order to summon, should have thought on that. Thanks man!